# Flask REST API responding with a JSONArray

Tags: android, python, json, rest, flask

I have created a simple REST API using Flask for an Android application. I'm having trouble implementing the GET method. It is supposed to return all the records in the form of a JSONArray. The response would look something like his

```
{
    "tasks": [{
               "task" : "Do it",
               "timestamp": 1433510946152
              },{..}
             ],
    "success": 1
}
```

My Task model looks like this

```
class Task(db.Model):   
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    task= db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    @staticmethod
    def newest():
        return Task.query.order_by(desc(Task.timestamp))

    def to_json(self):
        return dict(id=self.id,
                    task= self.task,
                    timestamp = self.timestamp)
```

The to_json() method converts the result into JSON. I just don't know how to use it appropriately. How would I put all the records inside of an JSONArray? Here is my method that gets all the tasks. I'm using Flask paginate too, so tasks is a pagination object.

```
def get_tasks():    

    page = request.args.get('page')
    if page is not None:
        try:
            page = int(request.args.get('page'))
        except:
            return jsonify({'result': 'Invalid parameter'})
    else:
        page = 1
    tasks= models.Task.newest().paginate(page, 7, True)

    #How do I return the tasks in an appropriate format?
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: something along `return jsonify(dict(tasks=[task.to_json() for task in tasks], success=1))`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to convert `tasks` into a JSONArray, put it inside of a JSONObject and then respond with it?

Comment: @Bidhan A yes that is exactly what I want to do. The JSONObject will have a JSONArray and an integer called success.

Comment: @njzk2 I don't think `for task in tasks` is going to work here since `tasks` is a pagination object.

Comment: @BidhanA: possibly `tasks.items` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply loop over your `tasks`, convert them into json using your to_json and store them inside of an array. For example:

```
def get_tasks():    

    page = request.args.get('page')
    if page is not None:
        try:
            page = int(request.args.get('page'))
        except:
            return jsonify({'result': 'Invalid parameter'})
    else:
        page = 1
    tasks= models.Task.newest().paginate(page, 7, True)
    # This list will hold all your tasks in JSON format
    jsontasks = []
    # Since tasks is a pagination object, you should use tasks.items
    for task in tasks.items:
        jsontasks.append(task.to_json())
    #How do I return the tasks in an appropriate format? Like this..
    return jsonify({'tasks': jsontasks, 'success': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks it worked..I was trying to use the to_json method on the tasks object itself. I needed to loop on the individual task and add them to a list. I get it now. Thanks again.