# Flask REST API Error: The view function did not return a valid response

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, flask

In a Flask REST API route in Python, the return type is a `list`

```
@app.route('/ent', methods=['POST'])
def ent():
    """Get entities for displaCy ENT visualizer."""
    json = request.get_json()
    nlp = MODELS[json['model']]
    doc = nlp(json['text'])
    return [
        {"start": ent.start_char, "end": ent.end_char, "label": ent.label_}
        for ent in doc.ents
    ]
```

This errors with:

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.
```

How can I get the API route on `/ent` to return a JSON array correctly?

Comment: Couldn't you change list to a hashable type like tuple and then convert it back to list? It's that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always convert the list into dict as needed by Flask as shown below

```
return { "data": [
        {"start": ent.start_char, "end": ent.end_char, "label": ent.label_}
        for ent in doc.ents
    ]}
```

Also have you seen [Flask REST API responding with a JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667979/flask-rest-api-responding-with-a-jsonarray?rq=1) ?

Answer (score 3):

The reason it is failing is because the views in Flask require a hashable return type. You can always convert your return values to hashable types viz string, dict, tuple etc and then transform from the result.

```py
return tuple([
        {"start": ent.start_char, "end": ent.end_char, "label": ent.label_}
        for ent in doc.ents
    ])
```